# How to render recursive component in React?

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I'm trying to render a component recursively. On each recursive call I subtract 10 px from the dimensions. I expect a series of nested divs, each one 10px smaller. When the height and width reach 10px, the component should return null, so that is my base case.

Instead of expected result, I've got nothing. No errors in the terminal, no errors in the dev tools, just a page that is frozen.

Any thoughts?

#### `RecurentDiv.js`:

```
const RecurentDiv = ({ width, height }) => {
  const style = {
    width: `${width - 10}px`,
    height: `${height - 10}px`,
    border: "1px solid black",
    display: "inline-block"
  };

  if (width < 10) return null; //base case

  return (
      <div style={style}>
        <RecurentDiv width={style.width} height={style.height} />
      </div>
  );
};

export default RecurentDiv;
```

#### `App.js`:

```
<RecurentDiv width={100} height={100} />
```

Comment: Please add you for loop code.

Comment: https://medium.com/@suraj.rajan/recursion-using-reactjs-components-3c871f99fb2f will help

Comment: @SvetoslavDimitrov There isn't any "for loop code" because it's a recursive function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<RecurentDiv width={style.width} height={style.height} />
                  //^^^^^^               ^^^^^^
```

`style.width` is a string, not a number: `${width - 10}px`. The code is doing `"100px" - 10` which evaluates to `NaN`, which is then passed into the next `RecurentDiv`'s props. The base case is never reached.

Instead, pass `width` and `height` numbers directly into the recursive component, subtracting the reduction amount to approach the base case.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```js
const RecurrentDiv = ({width, height}) => {
  const style = {
    width: `${width}px`,
    height: `${height}px`,
    border: "1px solid black",
    display: "inline-block"
  };

  return width < 10 ? null : (
    <div style={style}>
      <RecurrentDiv width={width - 10} height={height - 10} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<RecurrentDiv width={100} height={100} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```